# com class library registration

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, registry

i have created a com class library with vb.net. i have registered the dll with regasm. Then i imported and used it to a vb6 project. I have noticed that if i unregister the library and register it again then i get the following error:

Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)': Automation error.

In order to make the library usable again, i have to rebuilt the library with different ClassId, InterfaceId, EventsId at the classes and then register the new dll.

is this happening on purpose and this should be the functionality or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PS: it also does the same thing if i overwrite the registered file with the same file or if i rename its folder and then rename it back to its previous name. Rebuid and re-registered is needed.

Comment: What is the exact command line you are using to register and unregister? What does the regasm output say - does regasm report any error?

Comment: regasm mypath\mylib.dll. It is being registered successfully, otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: What about when you unregister - what is the command line output from regasm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `/codebase` command line when registering if you are not installing your assembly into the GAC (it must be strong-named to be able to do this)

Check out the [Regasm reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more info

Comment: Just to be clear, yes you should use the `codebase` option, and no it does not need to be strong-named.  Strong-named is only required to place it in the GAC.

Comment: @tcarvin - not according to the MS docs: `The assemblyFile argument that you specify with the /codebase option must be a strong-named assembly.`

Comment: No, that documentation is quite wrong.  The strong-name requirement is only there for the GAC.  You'll get a warning when you use /codebase ("you're about to create DLL Hell") but you can ignore it as long as you're doing this only on your dev machine.

Comment: I do it quite often for *private* assemblies used by a single application.  Dll hell only happens when you start sharing the assembly :)